# cURL response missing Location field

Tags: unix, curl, terminal

I am curling to a server that I own and getting a response. But this response is missing a Location field. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

This is the curl:

```
curl -I http://example.server.net/
```

And this the the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 15:08:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 15
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type:
```

As you can see there is no Location field that responds with something like:

```
Location: http://example.server.net
```

I know it is a valid field from other curls. I am looking for reasons why some basic fields might not be shown and possible solutions

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get `Location` header when response code is [3xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location).

For example:

```
$ curl -I http://g.cn
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.cn/
Date: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 15:29:10 GMT
Expires: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 15:29:10 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: gws
Content-Length: 218
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,80:quic
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there anyway to get a Location response for a 200 response code?

Comment: `Location` is for redirection. We don't need to redirect when code is 200.